# ajax call with javascript in django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkPin();" id="pin"/>
```

hi all i am new in django and i am trying to access database by views `def pincheck():` and i am trying this by javascript but ther is some error is occurred.

```
function checkPin(){
    var pin_code=document.getElementById("pin").value;
    if(pin_code.length == 6){        
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("innerHTML").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            else if (request.status === 404) {  
                alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
            }  
            else if (request.status === 403) {  
                alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
            }  
        }
      var data = "{% csrf_token %}";
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', data);
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "../../sellerprofile/ajaxcall/");
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

this is my javascript please correct me if wrong.
the error is `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

Comment: Use jquery.. it is simple , clean.. easy..

Comment: i could not use jquery..

Comment: i have to use vanilla js

Comment: though the title says django, this doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with django. and as @ZohaibIjaz use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are setting the header without actually opening the connection that's why it is giving **InvalidStateError**.
The right way to do is first open the connection then set the header. 
Below is your modified code.

```
function checkPin(){
var pin_code=document.getElementById("pin").value;
if(pin_code.length == 6){        
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("innerHTML").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else if (request.status === 404) {  
            alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        }  
        else if (request.status === 403) {  
            alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        }  
    }
  var data = "{% csrf_token %}";
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "../../sellerprofile/ajaxcall/");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', data);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

I hope it will work ;)

Comment: thank you so much for giving me this information... now its working fine... :)